# System monitor squashfs full is it normal?

Tags: filesystem, performance, optimization

My computer gets very slow after hours of working on it. I am wondering if it's not related to this and how to fix it ? Screenshot below shows system monitor output System monitor showing 5 devices full

[image]

Comment: No its not the `loop` devices.

Comment: Look at your `resource` tab check the `memory and swap` usage.

Comment: @George do you mean that is normal to have the 5 devices full ?

Comment: Those devices aren't used for normal data storage. The one you should be bothered about are the other two. Look at those five as `flash drives` used by `snap`.

Comment: From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS):SquashFS is a compressed read-only file system for Linux. SquashFS compresses files, inodes and directories, and supports block sizes up to 1 MB for greater compression. SquashFS is also the name of free software, licensed under the GPL, for accessing SquashFS filesystems.